# Query Firebase with AngularFire2 query getting only one object

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have a Object Observable

```
private Room = AngularFire.database.object(`/Rooms/`);
```

This observable has many values inside of it, but I have a child called `Empty`. That is set for `true` when empty and `false` when not.

I only want to query and get one room back from the observable. How do I go about doing this? Here is my first attempt without a query using `forEach` which is not something that I want to use.

```
this.Room.subscribe(list => {
      list.forEach(snapshot =>{
        if(snapshot.Empty == "true")
          console.log(snapshot);
      })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In AngularFire2, to query using a child value, you need to use a `list`:

```
AngularFire.database.list(`/Rooms/`, {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'Empty',
        equalTo: true
    }
});
```

The resultant observable will emit an array of entries under `Rooms` that have `Empty` set to `true`.

To retrieve a single child, you could specify `limitToFirst`:

```
AngularFire.database.list(`/Rooms/`, {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'Empty',
        equalTo: true,
        limitToFirst: 1
    }
});
```

The resultant observable will emit an array with a single entry in it (or an empty array if there are no matches). If the emitted entry changes and `Empty` is set to `false`, the observable will re-emit with the next matching entry (if there is one). If you are only interested in the first matching entry, you could use the RxJS [`first`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-first) operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
...
AngularFire.database.list(`/Rooms/`, {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'Empty',
        equalTo: true,
        limitToFirst: 1
    }
})
.first();
```

Comment: THis works thank you so much, but would you happen to know how to get back a static list or unsubscribe after it finds that one. Because after I set it to false it moves onto the next true

Comment: Thank you soo much

Comment: Missing "," after 'Empty'

Comment: @cartant I am using firebase real time database for chat feature. My requirement is, I want to call list method once (Which will get the all available data from fb) and get the message history to render after that I need to get the latest object added in current node and display or add that new object into current list. How do I do that?
The same thing I achieved with the help of once() and on() method but have used library for chat https://github.com/rpaschoal/ng-chat so can not able to manage the real time DB